# Suppressing Ada Restriction

Tags: ada

Is it possible to suppress an ada restriction in a particular part of your source? For example, if I have defined the use of "pragma Restrictions(No_Dynamic_Priorities)" at a high level, but want this restriction to be ignored in a place where I know what I'm doing is safe, is it possible to suppress this restriction so the compiler no longer complains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t explicitly negate a restriction; the only way to do it is to only apply the restriction to the units of your program that need it (that is, not "at a high level").

Restrictions are discussed in [ARM 13.12](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-13-12.html), and [(8.1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-13-12.html#p8.1) says

> A restriction may impose requirements on some or all of the units comprising the partition. **Unless otherwise specified for a particular restriction**, such a requirement applies to all of the units comprising the partition and is enforced via a post-compilation check.

In your particular case, [ARM D.7(9)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-D-7.html#p9) says for `No_Dynamic_Priorities`

> There are no semantic dependences on the package Dynamic_Priorities, and no occurrences of the attribute Priority.

which doesn’t override the general requirement; so I don’t think that what you want to do is allowed.